# Creating a component in react and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to convert this table below from react to typescript. I want to make it  universal table component where I can use for every data. This is a sample a table I created in react and its working well. In typescript, the class experts an interface which I have been finding it difficult to apply here.The table must be able to accept data from a webservice and display at any point in time. What am I supposed to add.

```
class Table extends Component {
    render() {
        const { characterData, removeCharacter } = this.props;

        return (
            <table className="table-bordered table-striped">
                <TableHeader />
                <TableBody characterData={characterData}
                        removeCharacter={removeCharacter}
                />
            </table>
        );
    }

}
const TableHeader = () => { 
    return (
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="300">Name</th>
                <th width="300">Job</th>
                <th width="300">Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    );
}
const TableBody = props => { 
    const rows = props.characterData.map((row, index) => {
        return (
            <tr key={index}>
                <td >{row.name}</td>
                <td >{row.job}</td>
                <td >{row.date}</td>
                <td><button onClick={() => props.removeCharacter(index)}>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        );
    });


    return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>;
}
export default Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can type check your props by adding chevrons next to the Component prototype. The first argument is type checking your props and the second argument will type check your internal state.

```js
interface TableProps {
  characterData: //...however the data should be structured
  removeCharacter: () => void;
}

interface TableState {
   //... this is empty because you haven't defined any internal component state
}

class Table extends Component<TableProps, TableState> {
    render() {
        const { characterData, removeCharacter } = this.props;
        return (
            <table className="table-bordered table-striped">
                <TableHeader />
                <TableBody characterData={characterData}
                        removeCharacter={removeCharacter}
                />
            </table>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the internal component state,the idea is to pass data to the table body. I am still not that good at react